# How to sort an arraylist of objects by a property?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Lets say you have an `Arraylist` of `HockeyPlayer` objects.

How could you sort that if they all have a variable **int goalsScored**.  How could you sort them by goalsScored?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890254/sort-arraylist, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206073/sorting-a-collection-of-objects and more.

Answer (score 96):

You can use [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) with a custom [`Comparator<HockeyPlayer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
    class HockeyPlayer {
        public final int goalsScored;
        // ...
    };

    List<HockeyPlayer> players = // ...

    Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<HockeyPlayer>() {
        @Override public int compare(HockeyPlayer p1, HockeyPlayer p2) {
            return p1.goalsScored - p2.goalsScored; // Ascending
        }

    });
```

The comparision part can also be written this way :

```
players.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(HockeyPLayer::goalsScored));
```

Alternatively, you can make `HockeyPlayer implements`[`Comparable<HockeyPlayer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). This defines *the* natural ordering for all `HockeyPlayer` objects. Using a `Comparator` is more flexible in that different implementations can order by name, age, etc.

#### See also

- [Java: What is the difference between implementing `Comparable` and `Comparator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator)

---

For completeness, I should caution that the `return o1.f - o2.f` comparison-by-subtraction shortcut must be used with extreme caution due to possible overflows (read: *Effective Java 2nd Edition: Item 12: Consider implementing `Comparable`*). Presumably hockey isn't a sport where a player can score goals in the amount that would cause problems =)

#### See also

- [Java Integer: what is faster comparison or subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction/2728858#2728858)

Comment: Do self-goals count as negatives? Because if `goalsScored` is strictly positive, then the subtraction trick is fine.

Comment: Own goals count as a goal for the last person on the other team who touched the puck, so `goalsScored` would never be negative. Even if it was negative though I think the subtraction trick still works.

Comment: `return p1.goalsScored - p2.goalsScored;` can be replaced by `return Integer.compare(p1.goalsScored,p2.goalsScored);` to avoid integer overflow if `goalsScored` can have negative value. Also since Java 8  this code can be replaced by `Collections.sort(players, Comparator.comparingInt(h -> h.goalsScored));`.

Comment: @Pshemo great solution, fixed a lookalike problem with your solution.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks this was useful when my property to compare is a long - I could use `return Long.compare(p1.getLongValue(), p2.getLongValue());`

Answer (score 7):

As @user6158055 suggets, it's one liner with `Java 8`, as follows:

```
Collections.sort(
                hockeyPlayerList,
                (player1, player2) -> player1.getGoalsScored()
                        - player2.getGoalsScored());
```

Complete example to depict the same:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<HockeyPlayer> hockeyPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
        hockeyPlayerList.add(new HockeyPlayer("A", 3));
        hockeyPlayerList.add(new HockeyPlayer("D", 10));
        hockeyPlayerList.add(new HockeyPlayer("B", 2));

        System.out.println("Before Sort based on goalsScored\n");

        hockeyPlayerList.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nAfter Sort based on goalsScored\n");

        Collections.sort(
                hockeyPlayerList,
                (player1, player2) -> player1.getGoalsScored()
                        - player2.getGoalsScored());

        hockeyPlayerList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static class HockeyPlayer {

        private String name;
        private int goalsScored;

        public HockeyPlayer(final String name, final int goalsScored) {
            this.name = name;
            this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getGoalsScored() {
            return goalsScored;
        }

        public void setGoalsScored(int goalsScored) {
            this.goalsScored = goalsScored;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "HockeyPlayer [name=" + name + ", goalsScored="
                    + goalsScored + "]";
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Before Sort based on goalsScored

HockeyPlayer [name=A, goalsScored=3]
HockeyPlayer [name=D, goalsScored=10]
HockeyPlayer [name=B, goalsScored=2]

After Sort based on goalsScored

HockeyPlayer [name=B, goalsScored=2]
HockeyPlayer [name=A, goalsScored=3]
HockeyPlayer [name=D, goalsScored=10]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just one line with Java 8 :

```
Collections.sort(players, (p1, p2) -> p1.getGoalsScored() - p2.getGoalsScored());
```

Comment: how to do the same for the property with string data type

Comment: btw i found out a way to sort for string                                    
                        `Collections.sort( 
                 people, 
                 (player1, player2) -> 
                    player1.getLastName().compareTo(player2.getLastName()));`

Answer (score 3):

Write a custom [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic Comparator like the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/).

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 this is simple

```
Collections.sort(playList, Comparator.comparingInt(HockeyPLayer::goalsScored))
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has a set of sort() methods  for this sort of thing. See Collections.sort (and Comparable) for details.