# Sort an ArrayList based on an object field

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts)

I am storing `DataNode` objects in an `ArrayList`. The `DataNode` class has an integer field called `degree`.
I want to retrieve `DataNode` objects from nodeList in the increasing order of `degree`. How can I do it.

```
List<DataNode> nodeList = new ArrayList<DataNode>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: On a second tought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts may be closer to this

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535124/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-property

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Modify the DataNode class so that it implements Comparable interface.

```
public int compareTo(DataNode o)
{
     return(degree - o.degree);
}
```

then just use

```
Collections.sort(nodeList);
```

Comment: [Beware of overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2728793/1553851) Much safer to `return Integer.compare(this.degree, o.degree);`

Comment: For some reason I get an error if I don't input an object

Comment: this will fail because there are no checks for null. Also you don't need the brackets

Comment: I'm getting an issue where I have to use `Object` as the type in the method call, and I can't cast that to my object type (DataNode in this example)

Comment: Your class has to implement Comparable<YourClass> and not just implement Comparable.

Answer (score 182):

Use a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(nodeList, new Comparator<DataNode>(){
     public int compare(DataNode o1, DataNode o2){
         if(o1.degree == o2.degree)
             return 0;
         return o1.degree < o2.degree ? -1 : 1;
     }
});
```

Comment: how about return(o1.degree - o2.degree);?

Comment: The proper way to do this is the way Mark coded it. Yes the simple one line of code will work 99.9 percent of the time. But you will have a problem if the result of the subtraction is a large number causing the high order bit to overflow. For example you would expect (Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-10)) to be postive, but it isn't.

Comment: @camickr What about o1.degree.compare(o2.degree)?

Comment: @BenAaronson, should work fine if working with "Integer" objects, but it won't work if using "int" variables since the comparTo(...) method only works on objects not primitives.

Comment: @camickr Good point

Comment: Java 8 update: Collection.sort(nodeList, Comparator.comparing(DataNode::getDegree)) or Collection.sort(nodeList, Comparator.comparingDouble(DataNode::getDegree)) if degree is an double instead of an Double

Comment: @Kazaag your comment should be the correct answer! :) The `Comparator.comparing...` methods can also be used with the `Stream`s API as in `nodesList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(DataNode::getDegree)).collect(Collector.toList())`

Comment: I'd give another upvote but 128 is a nice round number :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) to sort on any property in your custom class.