# How do I sort an ArrayList of Objects?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator, compareto

I'm quite new to this, so sorry if this is a trite question. I have an ArrayList where Node is a custom class. This is how I have defined it:

```
static class Node  implements Comparable<Node> {
    String nodeName;
    String[] borderingNodes;

    public Node(String nodeName, String[] borderingNodes) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
        this.borderingNodes = borderingNodes;
    }       

    public int compareTo(Node node) {
        if(borderingNodes.length > node.borderingNodes.length) {
            return 1;           
        }

        if(borderingNodes.length == node.borderingNodes.length) {
            return 0;           
        }

        if(borderingNodes.length < node.borderingNodes.length) {
            return -1;          
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I tried doing an `Arrays.sort(inputNodes)` where inputNodes is an ArrayList... However I got the error:

```
 no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Node>)
        Arrays.sort(inputNodes);
```

How do I correctly do this? My sort btw... has to sort on the size of the borderingNodes array.

Comment: If a collection extended boundaries of the array then it couldn't be sorted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Collections.sort(inputNodes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

`Arrays.sort` is intended for sorting *arrays*.

Your current `compareTo` method does not return an integer for every code path. You can use [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Integer%29)

```
public int compareTo(Node node) {
   return Integer.compare(borderingNodes.length, node.borderingNodes.length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're tring to sort a `List` using a function designed for arrays.

You can use [`Collections.sort(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) instead. It's meant for `List`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) (it takes an optional comparator if that's of interest).

Note that this will sort your collection in place (i.e. modify the original), and as such you may wish to take a copy.

Note also the [ordering tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html), which is well worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the compareTo method to make custom comparisons.
[How to override compareTo:](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-override-compareto-method-in.html)

```
public int compareTo(Node o)
{
     //return should be based on the fields in the class 

}
```

then just go like

```
Collections.sort(yourList);
```

Another good way of implementing custom comparator is like it this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066577/1479895).

```
Collections.sort(nodeList, new Comparator<Node>(){
     public int compare(Node o1, Node o2){
         if(o1.nodeName.compareTo(o2.nodeName) == 0)
             //implement custom compare based on another field
         return o1.nodeName.compareTo(o2.nodeName);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Collections.sort(nodes) to sort the elements where *nodes* is a subclass of any collection i.e. an ArrayList.
2. The node class can't be static since you want to compare different objects of the class Node.
3. @Override should be added before the compareTo(Node other) method
   since it overrides a method declared in the interface.
4. The class variables should either be public and accessed directly or
   private and accessed through a method.
5. The comparison in the compareTo(Node other) method can be simplified.

The resulting code would be something like:

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    private String nodeName;
    private String[] borderingNodes;

    public Node(String nodeName, String[] borderingNodes) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
        this.borderingNodes = borderingNodes;
    }       

    public int getBorderingNodesLength() {
        return borderingNodes.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node otherNode) {
        return Integer.compare(borderingNodes.length, otherNode.getBorderingNodesLength());
    }
}
```