# Sort A Java ArrayList<MyObject> by a propriety

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have this Object :

```
    public class AdresseReponse {

    private String     nom;
    private String     numero;
    private String     rue;
    private String     codePostal;
    private String     ville;
    private String     region;
    private String     pays;
    private Coordonnee coordonnees;
    private double     distanceFromThePrevious;
    private int        number;

// + all setters & getters
}
```

In a other class, I have an ArrayList :

```
ArrayList<AdresseReponse> etapes    = new ArrayList<AdresseReponse>();
```

and this methode :

```
public void testSort( AdresseReponse depart, AdresseReponse etape ) throws IOException, _Exception {...}
```

In this method, I do :

```
etapes.add(etape);
```

After, I need to sort etapes by distanceFromThePrevious.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Is this in C#? In that case I would suggest you to use IEnumerable List

Comment: No is this in Java, sorry, I should have clear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066538/sort-an-arraylist-based-on-an-object-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using java comparator.

After this

```
etapes.add(etape);
```

add

```
Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
Collections.sort(etapes, sorter);
```

Here sorter is the custom comparator that must be implemented.
And Sorter class (of which sorter is an instance) code goes something like this

```
class Sorter implements Comparator<AddressResponse>{
@Override
public int compare(AddressResponse a, AddressResponse b){
    if(a.getdistanceFromThePrevious() >= b.getdistanceFromThePrevious())
        return 1;
    else if(a.getdistanceFromThePrevious() < b.getdistanceFromThePrevious())
        return -1;
}
```

Hope this helps.