# How to sort an ArrayList of users by userNumber

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am doing an Access Control System and I have an `ArrayList` of `User` objects that contains a user number and other things. Here is a printed example of the list:

```
1;258;Pedro Pereira
2;3579;Pedro Miguens;A DEMO para LIC está pronta
9;391;João Silvério;Bem Vindo Criador
6;1234;joao
4;391;Miguel Fernandes;Telefonar ao João Manuel
```

How do I sort the `ArrayList` so that the `userList` is ordered without having to write the full code?

Comment: What is a user? What do you want to order by? What full code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an ArrayList based on an object field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066538/sort-an-arraylist-based-on-an-object-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, it could be something like:

`Collections.sort(userList, (user1, user2) -> user1.getId() - user2.getId());`

assuming you have an `ArrayList` of `User` beans called `userList`, each with a property called `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface for your user class and implement its `compareTo` method. You have option to choose which field or combination of fields you want to be as your key for sorting.

Next whenever you want to sort your list, you can use `Collection.sort(userList)`.