# How to sort user defined object in ArrayList

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an arraylist of objects by a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535124/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-property)

```
    public static void main(String args[]){

            List<Emp> unsortList = new ArrayList<Emp>();

            unsortList.add(new Emp(109));
            unsortList.add(new Emp(106));
            unsortList.add(new Emp(103));
            unsortList.add(new Emp(108));
            unsortList.add(new Emp(101));
    }

public class Emp {
Integer eid;
public Emp(Integer eid) {
    this.eid=eid;
}
}
```

Emp is user defined class & stored in ArrayList. How sort ArrayList.

Comment: You probably should have tried Google before asking your question here, there are LOTS of info on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Collections#sort(List list, Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

It allows you supply your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which you can use to define how the objects will be matched

Answer (score 1):

Implement `Comparable<Emp>` and use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) to sort the list

```
public class Emp implements Comparable<Emp> {
    Integer eid;

    public Emp(Integer eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Emp o) {
        return eid.compareTo(o.eid);
    }
}
```