# How to sort Arraylist of objects

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have ArrayList, which containst football teams (class Team). Teams have points and i want to sort them by number of points.

```
 public class Team {
     private int points;
     private String name;

     public Team(String n)
     {
         name = n;
     }

     public int getPoints
     {
         return points;
     }

     public void addPoints(boolean win)
 {
            if (win==true)
            {
    points = points + 3;
            }

            else if (win==false)
            {
            points = points + 1;
            }

}
 //...
 }
```

Main Class:

```
 List<Team> lteams = new ArrayList<Team>;

 lteams.add(new Team("FC Barcelona"));
 lteams.add(new Team("Arsenal FC"));
 lteams.add(new Team("Chelsea"));

 //then adding 3 points to Chelsea and 1 point to Arsenal

 lteams.get(2).addPoints(true);
 lteams.get(1).addPoints(false);

 //And want sort teams by points (first index with most points).
```

I did my comparator.

```
 public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Team> {


    @Override
    public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
        if (o1.getPoints() > o2.getPoints())
         {
             return 1;
         }
        else if (o1.getPoints() < o2.getPoints())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;    
    } 

}
```

now I wanna use it (in main class)

```
 Colections.sort(lteams, new MyComparator());
```

I want to see:

1. Chelsea
2. Arsenal
3. Barcelona

But it doesn't sort.

Comment: How are you adding points to the team? In the code you included the team objects are placed directly into the list, you show no separate references to them.

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: @Perception no seperate references to team objects are needed because he has reference to list object and can easily identify team object based on its name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14475630/922198

Comment: @Subin - sorry, but that's a ***huge*** assumption

Comment: @Perception just meant that it is possible :-) That could be the reason why his sort is not working

Comment: @OP can you post code corresponding to `//then adding 3 points to Chelsea and 2 points to Arsenal
`

Comment: You appear to be sorting on "points" which you never set so all the points are 0.

Comment: This code should work, the problem seems to be elsewhere. Just two things: your comparator should be a singleton, and you don't need to `else` if you `return`. Finally, simplify it to `return Integer.compare(o1.getPoints(), o2.getPoints());`

Comment: Thanks for posts guys! Im newbie so my questions could be stupid, im sorry for this.

Comment: @Perception Why I have to show references?

Comment: @Subin added code where i inserts points. Btw, its working now ! Ty.

Answer (score 30):

Source : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535124/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-of-objects-by-a-property)

You can use [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) with a custom [`Comparator<Team>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
    class Team {
        public final int points;
        // ...
    };

    List<Team> players = // ...

    Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<Team>() {
        @Override public int compare(Team p1, Team p2) {
            return p1.points- p2.points;
        }

    });
```

Alternatively, you can make `Team  implements`[`Comparable<Team>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). This defines *the* natural ordering for all `Team` objects. Using a `Comparator` is more flexible in that different implementations can order by name, age, etc.

#### See also

- [Java: What is the difference between implementing `Comparable` and `Comparator`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440134/java-what-is-the-difference-between-implementing-comparable-and-comparator)

---

For completeness, I should caution that the `return o1.f - o2.f` comparison-by-subtraction shortcut must be used with extreme caution due to possible overflows (read: *Effective Java 2nd Edition: Item 12: Consider implementing `Comparable`*). Presumably hockey isn't a sport where a player can score goals in the amount that would cause problems =)

#### See also

- [Java Integer: what is faster comparison or subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-what-is-faster-comparison-or-subtraction/2728858#2728858)

Comment: To solve the comparison problem you can just use `Integer.compare()`

Comment: That's basically what the OP did!? Except he did not create an anonymous class

Comment: Right at moment i need it. +1

Answer (score 13):

```
public class Team {
   private int points;
   private String name;

public Team(String n, int p) {
    name = n;
    points = p;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Team> lteams = new ArrayList<Team>();

    lteams.add(new Team("FC Barcelona", 0));
    lteams.add(new Team("Arsenal FC", 2));
    lteams.add(new Team("Chelsea", 3));

    Collections.sort(lteams, new MyComparator());

    for (Team lteam : lteams) {
        System.out.println(lteam.name + ": " + lteam.points + " points");
    }
}
```

}

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Team> {
@Override
public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
    if (o1.getPoints() > o2.getPoints()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (o1.getPoints() < o2.getPoints()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}}
```

**Output:**
Chelsea: 3 points
Arsenal FC: 2 points
FC Barcelona: 0 points

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually necessary to define a custom Comparator like this.

Instead, you can easily define one, when you want to sort your ArrayList.

## Since JAVA 8 using lamda

```
    // Sort version.
    Iteams.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getPoints));

    // Complete version.
    Iteams.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.getPoints().compareTo(o2.getPoints()));
```

Also there are options for **second comparator**, if objects are equals on the first:

```
    // e.g. if same points, then compare their names.
    Iteams.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getPoints).thenComparing(Team::getName));
```

Also note that the default sort option is ***ascending***, but you can set it to ***descending*** using:

```
    // e.g. Sort by points descending.
    Iteams.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getPoints).reversed());
```

That way, you can sort your ArrayList in different ways whenever you want, just by adding the method you want.