# How to sort bidimensional ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, string, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` that is a list of couple of values:

```
John, 12.3
Marcus, 35.0
Sue, 11.4
```

How to sort the list by amount?
If in this case there is a better way than using an ArrayList of an ArrayList, please tell me and tell me then how to sort it. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475556/how-to-sort-arraylist-of-objects

Comment: It sounds like your inner list of Strings is the ["John", "12.3"] but I can't really tell from your question. You could `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`, where your comparator determines the ordering.

Answer (score 3):

Instead I will recommend you to use a class and use class like comparable or comparator to sort.
Something like this:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    String name;
    double amount;

    Person(String n, double d) {
        name = n;
        amount = d;
    }

    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        if (amount != other.amount)
            return Double.compare(amount, other.amount);
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

and this is easy to implement and understand.

Comment: Can you make the same example with ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>?

Comment: @smartmouse This answer is suggestion to create `List<Person>` rather than `List<List<String>>`. If you don't want to use this suggestion then you will need to write your own `Comparator`, but approach from this answer is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some
>   collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method
>   (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control
>   over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order
>   of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to
>   provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a
>   natural ordering.

It'd be great if you could add more information about why you are using those values then I am sure a better approach can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this:

```
    Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<String> one, ArrayList<String> two) {
            // Replacements for using Double.parseDouble(string) later
            String value1 = one.get(1).replace(",", ".");
            String value2 = two.get(1).replace(",", ".");

            if (Double.parseDouble(value1) < Double.parseDouble(value2))
            return -1;
        else if (Double.parseDouble(value1) > Double.parseDouble(distanza2))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
        }
    });
```