# Jsoup: sort Elements

Tags: java, collections, jsoup

I need to sort a Jsoup Elements container by its ownText(). What is a recommended way to accomplish that?

Does convertinng it to an ArrayList first for use with [a custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890254/sort-arraylist/890470#890470) make sense?

BTW, I tried sorting it directly, as in `Collections.sort(anElementsList)` but the compiler complains:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for
the arguments (Elements). The inferred type Element is not a valid substitute for the 
bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jsoup [`Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) already implements [`Collection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), it's essentially a [`List<Element>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html),  so you don't need to convert it at all. You just have to write a custom [`Comparator<Element>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for [`Element`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) because it doesn't implement [`Comparable<Element>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (that's why you're seeing this compile error).

Kickoff example:

```
String html ="<p>one</p><p>two</p><p>three</p><p>four</p><p>five</p>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements paragraphs = document.select("p");

Collections.sort(paragraphs, new Comparator<Element>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Element e1, Element e2) {
        return e1.ownText().compareTo(e2.ownText());
    }
});

System.out.println(paragraphs);
```

Result:

```
<p>five</p>
<p>four</p>
<p>one</p>
<p>three</p>
<p>two</p>
```

#### See also:

- [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts/1814112#1814112)

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you!